# Name of file with ? at the end

Tags: java, file, terminal, finder

I have a series of files. When i see them, by terminal, i get this:

```
ls
filename1^J
filename2^J
filename3^J
filename4^J
```

But when i open them through Finder application i get this:

```
Finder
filename1
filename2
filename3
filename4
```

So, i make a simple Java program, based on the method below, to change their name e fix this situation:

```
String newPath = file.getAbsolutePath().replace("^J", "");
```

But it doesn't fix the problem. So, how can i rename those files?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/696816/remove-question-mark-from-file-names-osx

Comment: No idea why the previous comment was deleted but it gave a useful hint; it is very probably the case that your terminal lacks the glyph to display whatever is after the number, and it displays '?' by default.

Comment: The filename probably ends in a character which your terminal's character encoding can't display. Try printing `(int) filename.charAt(filename.length() - 1)`.

Comment: The last character is "^J" and i cannot delete it

Comment: If you ran the code Andy suggested, it would give you an int, which means a code-point, rather then an incorrect representation.

Comment: I solve the problem and i have put down the solution used for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this simple solution:

```
filename = filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]", "_");
```

I hope this can be useful to others